# Combinations in n-dimensions - How determine if Points see each other (If they are on same axis)

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations, n-dimensional

In n-dimensional grid (Max. 10^7 dimensions) are two points. They have imaginary sensors on every axis.
I need algorithm what will calculate all possible options when these two points can spot themselves.

**Formal written from my task document (translated to english):**
Let **A** with the coordinates **(a1, a2, ..., an)** and **B** with the coordinates **(b1, b2, ..., bn)**
are two points in n-dimensional space and exists **i ∈ 1, 2, ..., n** such that **ai = bi** then **A and B sees each other**

**Example:**
In ***1-dimensional*** space with ***length 10*** is total ***45 combinations*** how to put ***2 points*** when they see each other (They see each other every time).
It is easy combination 10C2 (10 of 2) = 45

*How to calculate it in 2,3,4,...,10^7 dimensions by program (I prefer C#)?*

**Proper test data what i have:**
Input:
1
10
Output: 45

Input:
2
5 8
Output: 220

Input:
3
8 12 11
Output: 14784

More explanation:
Output is number of combinations when two points in space see each other (are on same axis). In 1 dimensional space is only one axis so they see each other always. In 2 dimensional space are 2 axis, so they can see each other only in some case

[This image example explaining more than text i think](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iaaD.png)

Comment: Take a look at [ask].

Comment: Please give me same example with proper data and result.

Comment: I added test inputs and outputs to question

Comment: OK this good but please add answer with logic because why answer 45,220 and 14784.

Comment: when they do not see each other? do they have some kind of range of view or something?

Comment: @NayanDhamsaniya I only can imagine it in 1 and 2 dimensional space. Look at the image it describes problem more than text. 45 is because output is number of combinations when two points in space see each other (are on same axis). In 1 dimensional space is only one axis so they see each other always. In 2 dimensional space are 2 axis, so they can see each other only in some case

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja no they dont have they "see" to all in all directions to the end of space

Comment: So they se each other only if they are on the same axis, right? If so, on two dimentions of lenghs of 5 and 8 they have 5!/2!3! + 8!/2!6! = 38 ways

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja yes sure, they cant see point on other position. They "see" only on axis but range is unlimited.

Comment: @PJvG it is correct. Combination 10C2 = 45

Comment: Formal written from my task: Let A with the coordinates (a1, a2, ..., an) and B with the coordinates (b1, b2, ..., bn)
are two points in n-dimensional space and exists i ∈ 1, 2, ..., n such that ai = bi
, Points A and B sees each other

Comment: Are you sure your second example is correct? They can meet on first axis with lenght of 5, so on 10 ways and because we have 8 axis like this it is 80 possibilities to being on the same line in one dimention. Than we have second dimention of lenght of 8 so 29 possibilities times 5 lines like that so 145. In total its 80+145 = 225 ways to be on the same axis

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja it is absolutely correct. This is a document from college as the correspondence seminar

Comment: You think you need to use combinations, but really your problem should be solved using permutations. The number of permutations of a 1 dimension grid with 10 positions is 10*9 = 90.

Comment: yes i got it for why result 45. i will try and post of this after completed.

Comment: @PJvG but result must be 45. I get it why you think it will be 90 but it is all combinations with repeats i think. i need without repeats

Comment: Could someone explain second example? When I'm trying to count it i get 225 and second I get correctly (14784)

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja you must count bad. check if you dont have doubles. I've gradually got 45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10 = 220 (Every row number of combinations is lower X times and there is Y rows). It makes sense

Comment: Why is this question closed for seeking debugging help? This is an [algorithm] question which doesn't require code - OP just states that he would prefer an algorithm outlined in C# instead of pseudocode.

Comment: @le_m I can program it myself, I only needed some kind of logic like Arkadiusz Raszeja did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it's correct.
C(x,y) is combination x of y.
Lets say we have one dimention, lets call it X of lenght 8. There are C(8,2) = 8*7/2 = 28 possibilities to see eachother.
When we add second dimention, named Y, of lenght 12 now we have 12 lines parallel to X. So we have 12*28=336 possibilities to being found on all the lines parallel to X. Now, on Y dimention we have C(12,2) = 66 possibilities. And there are  8 lines like that so 66*8=528.
In total: 336 +528= 846 possibilities
Now lets add another dimention, labeled as Z with lenght of 11. There are C(1,2) = 11*10/2 = 55 in one line and (atention) we have 8*12 lines like that. So is it's 55*8*12 = 5280 possibilities!
Now in total we have:
Paralel to X axis: C(8,2)*11*12 = 3696
Parallel to Y axis C(12,2)*8*11 =  5808
Parallel to Z axis C(11,2)*8*12 = 5280
TOTAL = 14784
In general the formula for n dimentions with n1,n2... nk lenghts is:
Sum of C(ni,2) * (n1*n2...*nk)/ni
Or shorter:
sum of (n1*n2*n3...nk)/2 * (ni-1)

example:
dimentions with 3,8,9,11:
(3*8*9*11)/2*(3-1) = 2376
(3*8*9*11)/2*(8-1) = 8316
(3*8*9*11)/2*(9-1) = 9504
(3*8*9*11)/2*(11-1) = 11880
Total = 32076
The easiest equasion:
(n1*n2*n3...ni)(n1+n2+...ni - k)/2, where ni are lenghs, and k is number of dimentions

Comment: You are absolute genius man! I was on way to find out this because there is a rule that causes a linear decline when you doing this step by step. Hats off and thanks! This is right

Comment: I like to make me brain sweat :) Nice to help, and meet you :) I wish you menny successes on your career :)

Comment: I can send you all tasks from my correspondence seminar :D All tasks are mind blowing but this much more than others. It is in czech language so if you translate it you can solve it all and make your brain more hotter :D

Comment: shit for 11 dimensions it seems not workl lol :D why

Comment: the problem might be in lenght of int (or event unsigned int). It's about 2 mld, after multiplaying 11 numbers it might get crush. I'm Polish, my slavic brother :)

Comment: Try to construct your own type, like string containing number and then define operators like "*" or "+". Then lenght of your number can be almost infinit. uLong can handle 20 dogits, decimal 29. That is the limit of "normal" variables.

Comment: I figured that long is enough but still its not correct. I will make research but maybe just task is not good written :)

Comment: So you maybe can translate tasks better :D

Comment: why you think it's not correct? You get error, or you have different values than book requires? Send an example.

Comment: O got different. I will send it tommorow. I think its bad in task. not in algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I have create sample code so you can try it. i have check it's working fine.

Equation is : C(n,r)=n!/(r!(n−r)!)

**Example:**
**1.** 10C2=45
**2.** 10C3=120

```
public void Calc()
{
  int result= nCr(10, 3);
}

public int nCr(int n,int r )
{   
   int nValue=1;
   int rValue = 1;
   for (int i = n-r+1; i <= n; i++)
   {
       nValue = nValue*i;
   }
   for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++)
   {
        rValue = rValue*i;
   }
   return nValue/rValue;
}
```

Comment: How can i test it for 2 dimensional array with 5x8 grid? I think this is not right answer

Comment: this use only one dimensional please give me Equation for two dimensional so i will try it.

Comment: problem is it must be for n-dimensional, with maximal value 10^7 dimensions. And teachers says it can be done with complexity O(N)!!

Comment: problem is solved. thanks for your help.  @ArkadiuszRaszeja got it :D

Comment: Most welcome. good work. good work ArkadiuszRaszeja...

Comment: Can someone please upvote this? I have ban because downvotes on good questions :( @ArkadiuszRaszeja